# get the number of unique values in pyspark column

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with a column `URL` in it. All I want to know is how many distinct values are there. I just need the number of total distinct values. 
I have tried the following

```
df.select("URL").distinct().show()
```

This gives me the list and count of all unique values, and I only want to know how many are there overall. I want something like this - col(URL) has x distinct values.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`distinct().count()`** to get **`count of distinct`** values.

```
df.select("URL").distinct().count()
```

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,),(2,),(1,)],['id'])

df.show()
#+---+
#| id|
#+---+
#|  1|
#|  2|
#|  1|
#+---+

#to list out 20 distinct values
df.select('id').distinct().show()
#+---+
#| id|
#+---+
#|  1|
#|  2|
#+---+

#to get count of distinct values
df.select('id').distinct().count()
#2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
f.select(countDistinct("URL"))
```

Thants all